# Visual Studio --> Copy a selected control name to clipboard

Tags: visual-studio, copy, controls, clipboard

It is a pain to pick a button name from the "Properties" grid window or even from "Document Outline" window

I want something like :

- Right click a button or any other control in a form then from the context menu choose --> "Copy Name"
- or a Shortcut key to copy the control name to clipboard

can I have a macro to do that inside visual studio 2010
or is there extension to do that ??

any idea ??

Edit:
[CompCopy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RogerGRib.CompCopy) extension but for Visual Studio 2017 not Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [shortcut list](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/), there's no such a thing; but you can do it almost as easily as you said:

1. From the properties window, click the "AZ" button to sort your properties alphabetically; `(Name)`, i.e. the name of the control, will be the third from the top and will stay that way
2. Click the control you want to copy the name of, e.g. a button
3. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to select the property window, where the name will be there for you to copy

[image]

Comment: great solution Thanks, I added a shortcut Ctrl Shift P to show properties window then in autohotkey added this

#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe

^q::
Send ^+{p}
Send ^{Home}
Send {Down 2}
Send {Tab}
Send {F11}
Send {Esc}
#If